# How to add specific numbers to each element in an array? Java

Tags: java, arrays, element

I'm trying to add 10 to each element of the array but I am getting :

```
[-10.0, -9.0, -8.0, -7.0, -6.0, -5.0, -4.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
```

what I want is

```
[-10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0, 100.0, 110.0]
```

Any help will be appreciated thanks.
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ReportCardClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[] a1 = new double[13];

        for(int i=-0; i < a1.length; i++) {
             a1[i]=i-10; 

        }


        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a1));

        /*
         * create an array marks for 13 double values
         * assign values, using a loop, such that,
         * first value is -10
         * second value is 0
         * third value is 10
         * fourth value is 20
         * ...
         */
```

Comment: whats the input array?

Comment: add 10? perhaps you meant substract 10??

Comment: There is no such thing as `-0`.

Comment: "I'm trying to add 10 to each element " - I don't see you add anything to the array. The only thing that comes close is `a1[i]=i-10; ` but that's actually _subtracting_.

Comment: Change it from `i-10` to `10i-10`.

Comment: @Gendarme, what is `10i-10` ?!?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Is that a rhetorical question?

Comment: no, IMO that will produce a compile error

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Written as is, yes. But it should be expanded to `a1[i]=(10*i)-10;`.

Comment: Oh, of course. Brainfart on my part omitting the multiplication operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(int i=0; i < a1.length; i++) {
     a1[i]=(i-1)*10; 

}
```

An alternative solution by [Gendarme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221346/gendarme) is to replace `a1[i]=i-10;` by `a1[i]=(10*i)-10;`

Comment: that would produce 0 for the first item, not as required

Comment: @SharonBenAsher No it wouldn't.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Why? (0-1) => -1, -1*10 => -10.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher No worries :)

Comment: my* ha ha ha ha